# CakePHP/php - reformatting array results

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have the following array which I obtain using sql from cake..

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'users' => 
        array (size=1)
          'user_status' => boolean false
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'user_count' => string '17' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'users' => 
        array (size=1)
          'user_status' => boolean true
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'user_count' => string '4' (length=1)
```

I have a  flag field for active/not active users, which holds boolean value either, true or false. I woul like to iterate over that array and change the value of false to not active, and true to active.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
foreach($results as $result){
        if($result['users']['user_status'] == false){
            $result['users']['user_status'] = 'not active';
        }else{
            $result['users']['user_status'] = 'active';
        }
    }
```

Any other way  could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($results as &$result) {
    if($result['users']['user_status'] === false){
        $result['users']['user_status'] = 'not active';
    } else {
        $result['users']['user_status'] = 'active';
    }
}
```

This way you are saving the values in the `$results` array

Comment: Thanks cornelb! How does this work exactly? I have been using php for about 10 months know but never came across this.

Comment: You can read more about references here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Long story short, without reference (the `&`) you're copying each iteration into `$result`, so any modification to this variable won't affect `$results`. But by reference, you're able to modify the original array by modifying `$result`